# How do I get just the surface of a complex object (with a lot of overlaps)?

Tags: modeling, procedural, shrinkwrap

I'm using Blender to create some procedural shapes by using textures and modifiers. Whith this process, I get a lot of overlapping, as some faces get though other faces and the normals are probably a mess.

[image]

Of course this object has A LOT of useless internal geometry that I would like to get rid of. My first thought was to use the Shrinkwrap modifier, but even with a lot of vertices it gets "stuck" in those "spikes" of the shape.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the Voxel Remesher?

Comment: Perhaps ..........In Edit mode, Wireframe mode, Open the Select menu > Select All by Trait > and try the various options, Non Manifold, Loose geometry, or Interior faces?   Or select all and Mesh menu > clean Up< and maybe one of the options there may help? Don't forget to save a copy of your model to disk before trying any of those :)